# Will DVD Studio Pro work on an Intel Mac?

Tags: macos, dvd-studio-pro

I am looking at using DVD Studio Pro on an Intel MBP. 
1. Which version will work?
2. How much control do I have over the DVD?

This is kinda two questions, so if needed I can split it. Just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DVD Studio Pro 4.1 is the first Intel comparable version of the software. I believe that came with Final Cut Studio.

You have great control over DVD authoring. The best if not only solution on the Mac. Menus, scripting, tracks, etc.

Comment: I have 4.1 and it doesn't install on intel machines

Comment: [DVD Studio Pro is certainly designed for both PPC and Intel processors](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/DVD_Studio_Pro_4.1_lbn_z.pdf).